# Background geolocation not work in ionic 3 in background

Tags: android, background, geolocation, ionic3, tracking

Cordova plugin background-geolocation does not work when the app is in the background in Ionic 3. This code called in the app.component.ts file. This code calls that webservice on foreground only not in background or in screen off.

```
 startTracking() {
    // Background Tracking
    let config = {
      desiredAccuracy: 0,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 10, 
      debug: true,
      interval: 2000 
    };
    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {
      console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
      // Run update inside of Angular's zone
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.geoLatitude = location.latitude;
        this.geoLongitude = location.longitude;
        this.TrackLiveLocation();//for call our private webservice
    });
      });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
    this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
    // Foreground Tracking
  let options = {
    frequency: 3000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  };
  this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {
    console.log(position);
    // Run update inside of Angular's zone
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.geoLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.geoLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
      this.TrackLiveLocation();//for call our private webservice
    });
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Native v/s Hybrid
A side impact of the latest updates of Android 8 onwards is that location APIs will require native app development.
because Direct control through hybrid frameworks like React Native, Flutter, Cordova, Ionic, or Xamarin will no longer work.
Hybrid app developers will need to build native functionality for location access.

ionic plugin is working for foreground but not working in background as per latest Android policy and update for background service.

[policy for background mode](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)